# Highchart: endOnTick not finishing with the max extreme set for xaxis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

We are using Highchart's API for generating some line charts. One of the requirement for these charts is that we should end the xAxis scale with the last xAxis value of the data provided and show that tick label for it.

Data: [[2014-08-28,.434],[2014-10-17,.234],[2014-11-5,.134],[2015-01-12,.274]]

Expected:

Last plot for xAxis on: 2015-01-12 (Line chart finish at the end of the chart area)

Last tick label for xAxis: Jan '12

Actual (http://jsfiddle.net/u2pa6qqL/3/):

Last plot for xAxis: 2015-01-12(gap between the last plot and the end of the chart area)

Last tick label for xAxis: Feb'15

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Chart reflow is set to true'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'When resizing the window or the frame, the chart should resize'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            endOnTick: true,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%b %e'
            },            
        },

        series: [{
            data: [[new Date('2014-08-28').getTime(),.434],[new Date('2014-10-17').getTime(),.234],[new Date('2014-11-5').getTime(),.134],[new Date('2015-01-12').getTime(),.274]]
        }]
    });
});
```

I have tried with highchart settings showLastLabel, endOnTick, the xAxis extreme MAX & Min and setExtreme. nothing worked.

Can anyone please shed some light on this,

Thanks,
Sarath

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions) or [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) to print ticks in defined positions.